# Are the spawn eggs in the Minecraft creative inventory sorted by some rule?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This question was bothering me already some time, so I decided to ask:

In the Minecraft creative inventory, you can take any (except the Wither and Ender Dragon) mob spawn egg from the slot named miscellaneous. The eggs are ordered there in this order:

[image: My list of Minecraft spawn eggs]

The order of the eggs makes no sense to me. It isn't ordered alphabetically, by date of addition to the game, nor by anything else I see. It also could be that hostile mobs are first, then are peaceful mobs, just there is the Bat egg in the middle of the hostile mobs' eggs, the Wither Skeleton in between peacefull mobs, and the hostile mobs at the end.

**Are the eggs sorted in a specific order (by some rule)? If yes, what's the rule?**

Comment: looks like they get rarer to find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're ordered mainly by the numeric [Entity ID](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values/Entity_IDs) of what they spawn, which used to also be the damage value of the eggs.

Here's an ID table of most the mob eggs in your screenshot:

```
╔═════╦══════════════════════╗
║ ID  ║        Entity        ║
╠═════╬══════════════════════╣
║  50 ║ Creeper              ║
║  51 ║ Skeleton             ║
║  52 ║ Spider               ║
║  55 ║ Slime                ║
║  56 ║ Ghast                ║
║  57 ║ Zombie Pigman        ║
║  58 ║ Enderman             ║
║  59 ║ Cave Spider          ║
║  60 ║ Silverfish           ║
║  61 ║ Blaze                ║
║  62 ║ Magma Cube           ║
║  65 ║ Bat                  ║
║  66 ║ Witch                ║
║  67 ║ Endermite            ║
║  68 ║ Guardian             ║
║  69 ║ Shulker              ║
║  90 ║ Pig                  ║
║  91 ║ Sheep                ║
║  92 ║ Cow                  ║
║  93 ║ Chicken              ║
║  94 ║ Squid                ║
║  95 ║ Wolf                 ║
║  96 ║ Mooshroom            ║
║  98 ║ Ocelot               ║
║ 100 ║ Horse (Donkey, Mule) ║
║ 101 ║ Rabbit               ║
║ 102 ║ Polar Bear           ║
║ 120 ║ Villager             ║
╚═════╩══════════════════════╝
```

The original assignment of these seems to be mainly order of them being added, with neutral/hostile/ambient mob IDs starting at `50` (with non-living entities before `50`) and passive mobs starting at `90`.

The entities that don't follow this pattern are the ones for which spawn eggs were just added:

```
╔════╦═════════════════╗
║ ID ║     Entity      ║
╠════╬═════════════════╣
║  5 ║ Wither Skeleton ║
║  6 ║ Stray           ║
║ 23 ║ Husk            ║
║ 28 ║ Skeleton Horse  ║
║ 29 ║ Zombie Horse    ║
║ 27 ║ Zombie Villager ║
║  4 ║ Elder Guardian  ║
╚════╩═════════════════╝
```

I suspect these last ones, due to being added after the spawn egg stopped having the damage value of the entity it spawns, were just tacked on the end in the order they were made into separate entities, despite their IDs being lower and them not being passive mobs.

Comment: So what does, for example the bat do there?

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek The bat is classed as an "ambient" mob, rather than a passive one. They have a separate spawn cap to passive mobs, for example.

Comment: Ok, didn't know that. Thanks and +1